# Меняется глобальная переменная js

Tags: javascript

объявляю переменную, но она меняется если изменить другую переменную, как сделать что бы переменная DefaultSetting оставалась в первоначальном виде

```js
var setting, DefaultSetting;
setting = {
  'mose' :1,
  'mose2' :2,
};

DefaultSetting = setting;

setting['mose2'] = 7;

console.log(DefaultSetting);
```

Нужно DefaultSetting = `{"mose": 1,"mose2": 2}`

Comment: Полезно почитать: https://learn.javascript.ru/object-copy

Answer (score 4):

В `js` объекты передаются по ссылке, и не копируют содержимое.

Такая запись

```
DefaultSetting = setting
```

... просто получила ссылку на setting

```js
var setting, DefaultSetting;
setting = {
  'mose' :1,
  'mose2' :2,
};

// Скопировать на новый объект
DefaultSetting = Object.assign({}, setting);

setting['mose2'] = 7;

console.log(DefaultSetting);
```